# how can I use google map on rviz?

Tags: ros, navigation, robot-localization, pgm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have use robot_localization with gps/imu/odometry.

but I need add a outdoor map on rviz.

map_server need a map(type of pgm) and yaml.

I need a google map type of pgm.

I have no idea.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276809/how-can-i-use-google-map-on-rviz?/) by [wings0728](https://answers.ros.org/users/32538/wings0728/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2017-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could take a look at [mapviz](http://wiki.ros.org/mapviz). It's not RViz, but similar enough.

Less of a complete solution (and an actual RViz plugin): [gareth-cross/rviz_satellite](https://github.com/gareth-cross/rviz_satellite).

Another option might be [osm_cartography](http://wiki.ros.org/osm_cartography).

I haven't used either, but I know the ppl behind `mapviz` and that is well maintained, sees a lot of usage and is still actively developed.

---

Edit: comment by @tfoote:

> there's also [rqt_marble](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_marble) and [marble_plugin](http://wiki.ros.org/marble_plugin)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-11-28**:
+1 for mapviz the pure 2D interface is often better for these sorts of applications, there's also [rqt_marble](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_marble) and [marble_plugin](http://wiki.ros.org/marble_plugin)

**Comment by [wings0728](https://answers.ros.org/users/32538/wings0728/) on 2017-11-28**:
thank you ~